# Performing a 'Click' on a WebButton of type submit

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I'm having a bit of an issue with a button click on a test I developed, no error is thrown but a warning is due to smart identification finding the webButton I want rather than my script.

It's a pretty simple line:

```
Browser("ControlPoint").Page("Categories").WebButton("CategoryPublish").Click
```

Essentially in the test it will sit for a good 15seconds before actually clicking the button.  When reviewing the test run results I can then see the warning which states: object not found.

However, this exists in the object repository, if I debug and use 'Highlight in Application' it will instantly highlight the correct button.

The only things that stick out to me about this are that it's a webButton of type submit, I'm pretty certain this is used elsewhere in other tests but I'm not currently staring at somewhere it has been used.  Secondly, AFTER the button has been successfully clicked, a slider appears over the area the button was, with a text input and new buttons.  However, the click action on this new button works without problem.

Any suggestions?  Is there a way I can provide other properties rather than name or additional properties?

**EDIT**
I re-added the button to the object repository, which wound up with a different type, this time of button.  I turned smart ID off and it was working in the object repository, however when running the test the same problem occurred again.

I also tried to use further description without success, this is what I used that didn't improve things:

```
Browser("ControlPoint").Page("Categories").WebButton("name:=CategoryPublish","type:=submit").
```

Here's the Object properties for the button as requested, in its original form:

[image: properties]

Comment: Can you provide the snapshot of identification properties of WebButton("CategoryPublish")?

Comment: You can add properties to the identification properties using the plus button in the OR editor.

Comment: Hi @VinothS I've added the properties now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in other replies this was mainly an issue with identification.  I cannot explain why things happened the way they did but my suspicions on the WebButton type being 'Submit' had some grounds.

Essentially I used the object spy again to pick out the buttons in question and this time they were of type 'button'

They were originally added using the object spy so I've no idea how they ended up having a different type but there it is!  To be sure you've added your objects correctly, always set Smart Identification to false when debugging, I know this is a feature I'll be using more heavily in future!

*EDIT*

The comment below refers to trying to correct this same problem in another place and it wasn't working.  I managed to get to the bottom of the issue in this case as well, it seemed someone had manually changed the description property name to be in line with the name used in the object repository.  This meant it still couldn't be found after changing the button type in this case.

Comment: I previously deleted this because it worked, then it didn't...now it works again!  I guess time will tell on this one but I'd definitely like to see alternative solutions

Answer (score 1):

This problem is rather not about function that clicks object, but finding, or identifying object.

There can be few problems with this button:
1. Check in repository manager that you have unique description properties AND Ordinal identifier set properly: usually should be set to *'Type, Value: None'*, Or *'Index: 0'*
2. Try to read object dynamically, by *Description.Create*, and in debug mode check how many *childObjects(objDescription)* objects it returns by *.count()*. Then you can use *obj(i).highlight* in console, or evaluate parameters, and check what is wrong.

BUT! If it will highlight dynamically collected object, and click still won't work, then use *fireEvent* on this object, or drag/drop, or change replay type before clicking:

```
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1
```

Or if you can press enter instead of clicking you can make simple workaround:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: Hi Artur, how can I ensure uniqueness?  I mean I have it in the object repository and it highlights when not running in the test, so surely this is covered?  If not, how can I provide additional arguments to the click function to ensure I get the right button?  For example:     Browser("ControlPoint").Page("Categories").WebButton("CategoryPublish").Type("Submit").Click

I would really like to avoid sendKeys as clearly this does work, there is just a strange problem with identification as you've mentioned

Comment: In short, I have a webButton, I know its type is submit, is there any way I can use this with the Click function in order to make sure it hits the right button in this case?

Comment: Turn off smart identification globally, or just for this test object. You will see the highlight feature will then fail to find the button, too. It currently seems to work there because it uses smart identification, but without the delay because it tries smart identification immediately after "standard recognition" failed. You need to make the standard recognition properties unique. Smart id should only used and configured after that works. It just is an additional (and optional) safety net.

Comment: thank you @TheBlastOne I didn't appreciate smart ID was at work even when I was asking it to highlight.  I find it strange given that I added this using the object spy!  I have some ideas to try and we shall see where that gets me!

Answer (score -2):

I have had this problem before and happens a lot actually. As Artur was stating above it is with finding the object.  Try

> If Browser("ControlPoint").Page("Categories").WebButton("CategoryPublish").Exist(1) Then
>     Browser("ControlPoint").Page("Categories").WebButton("CategoryPublish").Click
>     End If

Or you could combine Artur's technique with ...

> Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
>   If Browser("ControlPoint").Page("Categories").WebButton("CategoryPublish").Exist(1) Then
>   objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
>   End If

This way you would keep your uniqueness.  If it is still having a problem finding it.  Check your console log to see if it is having problems finding the object itself and adjust the timing if needed.  Or use a while loop that has an incrementing int to stop it just in case.

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't help, in fact that's exactly what it currently does.  If it can't find the object, why would an if statement help?

As Artur stated send keys is an option but it's one I'd rather avoid.  I have an idea that may work, if it does I'll post it here as an answer.

Thank you for taking the time to offer your answer though

Comment: Use the .Net Windows Form Spy and substitute what you need for the object's name.